# Tensor derivatives of a second order tensor function with respect to itself

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

In a continuum mechanical context, let $\mathbf{A}$ be a second order tensor function.
We consider our operations in an orthonormal context

$$\mathbf{A} = A_{ij}\, \mathbf{e}_i\otimes\mathbf{e}_j\tag{1}$$

How do I calculate the derivatives

$$\cfrac{\partial\mathbf{A}}{\partial\mathbf{A}} = \cfrac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{kl}} \tag{2}$$

and

$$\cfrac{\partial\mathbf{AA}}{\partial\mathbf{A}} = \cfrac{\partial A_{ij}\,A_{jk}}{\partial A_{lm}}\tag{3}$$

or namely, is there an algorithmic basis on which I can take the derivatives of arbitrary indicial expressions such as above?

The thing is, I already know the answers from literature. For (1), the answer is simply given as $\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}$, but I don't know exactly how that is derived.

For (2), according to the literature, the product rule should be utilized such as

\begin{align*}
\cfrac{\partial A_{ij}\,A_{jk}}{\partial A_{lm}}&=\cfrac{\partial A_{ij}}{\partial A_{lm}}A_{jk}+A_{ij}\cfrac{\partial A_{jk}}{\partial A_{lm}}\\
&=\delta_{il}\delta_{jm}A_{jk}+A_{ij}\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}\\
&=(\delta_{il}A_{mk}+A_{il}\delta_{km})\,\,\, \text{with the basis}\,\,\,
\mathbf{e}_i\otimes\mathbf{e}_k\otimes\mathbf{e}_l\otimes\mathbf{e}_m\tag{4}
\end{align*}

But how do we prove that the product rule yields a valid result in the context of these multi-dimensional objects?
Can I define an algorithm for the differential operator that doesn't expand using the product rule but somehow using the indices?

Just to give a different perspective, let's assume temporarily that $\mathbf{A}$ is a simple tensor consisting of the dyadic product of two vector functions

$$\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b} = a_i b_j \,\,\mathbf{e}_i\otimes\mathbf{e}_j\tag{5}$$

Then (3) would be of the form

$$\cfrac{\partial a_i b_j a_j b_k}{\partial a_l b_m}\tag{6}$$

What types of strategies can be used when approaching this? Note that I am assuming that these objects are completely separate from geometry, i.e. just multi-dimensional arrays of scalar functions.

Comment: Well, if these are just arrays, and you use index notation, then the operations your indices onbscure are sums of products. If the product rule works for $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ functions, then it should work for your arrays, since your arrays contain sums of products, and differentiation is additive.

Comment: What about the case when A is a simple tensor?

Comment: Isn't (1) straightforward? You get a 1 on differentiating $A_{ij}$ w.r.t $A_{kl}$ if $i=j$ and $k=l$. For other cases it is zero.  The same is used in (2). The product rule is perfectly valid there.

Comment: You confuse in (2) and (3) the (4th order) tensors with the (scalar) components of these tensors. I.e. those "equalities" do not make sense. You can use the product rule leading up to (4) because you are working with the (scalar) components.