# Derivative of inverse of second-order tensor with respect to tensor using indices

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

my question is related to evaluating the derivatives of products of tensors using indices. I have gone through the questions already asked on math.stackexchange, (search on tensor derivative yields 902 results, only [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/788324/152405) is closer but still unanswered) but after going through them for one week, I couldn't find the answer. So unfortunately here comes another question related to tensor derivatives.

I have a tensor ${\bf F}$ (deformation gradient in solid mechanics) and I have dozens of relations where I need derivatives of  tensorial functions 
$$\mathbb G(\bf F) = \frac{\partial {\boldsymbol \sigma}(\bf F)}{\partial \bf F}$$
I know that derivative of $\bf F$ with itself is the fourth rank identity tensor $\mathbb I$: 
$$ 
\frac{\partial \bf F}{\partial \bf F}  = {\bf I}\overline {\otimes} {\bf I} = \mathbb I
$$
or in indical notation:
$$
\frac{\partial F_{ij}}{\partial F_{pq}} = \delta_{ip} \delta_{jq}
$$
given that components of $\bf F$ are not inter-related through further dependency.

The problem comes in when evaluating product of two tensors, example:
$$
\frac{\partial (\bf F^{-1}\cdot \bf F)}{\partial \bf F} = \frac{\partial (F^{-1}_{ij}\cdot F_{jk})}{\partial F_{pq}} {\bf e_i}\otimes{\bf e_k}\otimes{\bf e_p}\otimes{\bf e_q}  = {\bf 0}
$$
**Question:**
is it correct to write above equation, using chain rule as:
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial (\bf F^{-1}\cdot \bf F)}{\partial \bf F} &= \frac {\partial\bf F^{-1}}{\partial \bf F} \cdot {\bf F} + {\bf F^{-1}} \cdot \frac {\partial\bf F}{\partial \bf F} \\
&= \left[ \frac{\partial F^{-1}_{ij}}{\partial F_{pq}}\,F_{jk} + F^{-1}_{ij}\,\frac{\partial F_{jk}}{\partial F_{pq}} \right] {\bf e_i}\otimes{\bf e_k}\otimes{\bf e_p}\otimes{\bf e_q} = {\bf 0}
\end{split}
$$
The terms in square brackets now become:
$$
\begin{split}
\, & \frac{\partial F^{-1}_{ij}}{\partial F_{pq}}\,F_{jk} + F^{-1}_{ij}\,\frac{\partial F_{jk}}{\partial F_{pq}} = 0 \\
\Longrightarrow & \frac{\partial F^{-1}_{ij}}{\partial F_{pq}} =  -
 F^{-1}_{ij}\,\frac{\partial F_{jk}}{\partial F_{pq}} F^{-1}_{jk} \\
&\quad \qquad =  - F^{-1}_{ij}\,\delta_{jp} \delta_{kq} F^{-1}_{jk}  
\end{split}
$$
So the final result is:
$$
\frac{\partial F^{-1}_{ij}}{\partial F_{pq}} =  - F^{-1}_{ip}\, F^{-1}_{jq}
$$
However, in [Matrix Cook Book (page 10 eq. 60)](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) (MCB), and this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_derivative_(continuum_mechanics)#Derivative_of_the_inverse_of_a_second-order_tensor), the result is:
$$
\frac{\partial F^{-1}_{ij}}{\partial F_{pq}} =  - F^{-1}_{ip}\, F^{-1}_{qj} 
$$
The interchanged indices mean that my formulation has transposed the "actual" result (as per MCB and Wikipedia).

**What is wrong with the derivation method using indices, which I have used.**

Thanks.

**Note:** please note that my question is not about the derivative of inverse of a tensor, but the method itself, i.e. derivative of an expressions consisting of products of tensors, with respect to a tensor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the Euclidean space $\Bbb R^3$ is described by an orthonormal basis. The notation with indices is incorrect, since the index $j$ appears three times in one term (see e.g. this article about the [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)). Moreover, the dot-product of two second-order tensors $\boldsymbol{F}$ and $\boldsymbol{F}^{-1}$ satisfies
$$
F_{\ell k} F^{-1}_{kj} = \delta_{\ell j} \, .
$$
Since $j$ is repeated twice in one term, it is correct to rename it $\ell$:
$$
\frac{\partial F_{ij}^{-1}}{\partial F_{pq}} F_{jk} + F_{ij}^{-1} \frac{\partial F_{jk}}{\partial F_{pq}} = \frac{\partial F_{i\ell}^{-1}}{\partial F_{pq}} F_{\ell k} + F_{i\ell}^{-1} \frac{\partial F_{\ell k}}{\partial F_{pq}} \, .
$$
Hence, multiplying by $F^{-1}_{kj}$ on the right, one has
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial F_{ij}^{-1}}{\partial F_{pq}} &= - F_{i\ell}^{-1}  \frac{\partial F_{\ell k}}{\partial F_{pq}} F_{kj}^{-1} \\
&= -F_{i\ell}^{-1} \delta_{\ell p} \delta_{k q} F_{kj}^{-1} \\
&= -F_{i p}^{-1} F_{qj}^{-1} \, .
\end{aligned}

Comment: ah .. Thanks for the correction, yes those three j's in indices are the culprit. It is clear now. Thanks!